# How to break a long line of html code into multiple lines as "\" will do in python and C/C++

Tags: html, django, django-templates

Suppose that I have the following code,

```
<p>aaa<a>bbb</a>ccc</p>
```

the rendered web page will be like this

[image]

However, when the text "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" becomes pretty long, I want to split this single line into multiple lines for readability, like

```
<p>
    aaa
    <a>
        bbb
    </a>
    ccc
</p>
```

But the rendered web page will be like

[image]

There are whitespaces between two blocks of text. How can I make these lines work as the single line mentioned before. In python or C/C++, I can simply use "\" to notify the consecutive lines should be treated as a single line. Is there a similar funtionality in html file?

Besides, as I'm using django template system, I tried the django official tag "spaceless". According to django's doc, "spaceless" tag should remove the whitespace between html elements. But in this case, the whitespace between two blocks of text remains. I get pretty puzzled about this.

Thanks for any help!

I tried to ask chatgpt, github copilot and search on google. But I found no functionality in html that can make consecutive lines work as a single line. A similar functionality to "\" in python and C/C++ which inform compiler to treat consecutive lines as a single line is just what I want. Besides, if anyone can help find out why "spaceless" tag fails to remove the whitespace between two blocks of text, it will be so great!

Comment: In HTML, there isn’t a direct equivalent to the “\” line continuation character in Python or C/C++. 

although it could be done in these two ways:

CSS: You can use CSS properties like white-space, word-break, or word-wrap to control how whitespace is handled1.

JavaScript Template Literals: In JavaScript, you can use template literals (backticks) to write multiline strings without introducing newlines in the resulting string2.

Django’s spaceless Tag: Django’s {% spaceless %} tag removes whitespace between HTML tags, not the text nodes

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML (SGML) comments, like so:

```
aaa<!--
-->bbb<!--
-->ccc
```

Alternatively, you could include newline characters in your tags rather than in content eg.:

```
<p>
    aaa<a
       >bbb</a
    >ccc
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! I follow the second method and it works pretty well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use VS code extensions for this type of decoration in HTML code! for example: Emmet

Answer (score 0):

you can now use display:flex in your css to fix this.

```css
p{
display:flex;}
```

```html
<p>
aaa
<a>bbb</a>
ccc
</p>
```